# Understanding window function frame with RANGE mode

Tags: sql, postgresql, window-functions

```
SELECT
    sum(unique1) OVER () AS total,
    sum(unique1) OVER 
    (PARTITION BY four ORDER BY unique1 RANGE BETWEEN 5::int8 PRECEDING AND 6::int2 FOLLOWING),
    unique1,
    four
FROM
    tenk1
WHERE
    unique1 < 10;
```

return:

```
 total | sum | unique1 | four
-------+-----+---------+------
    45 |   4 |       0 |    0
    45 |  12 |       4 |    0
    45 |  12 |       8 |    0
    45 |   6 |       1 |    1
    45 |  15 |       5 |    1
    45 |  14 |       9 |    1
    45 |   8 |       2 |    2
    45 |   8 |       6 |    2
    45 |  10 |       3 |    3
    45 |  10 |       7 |    3
(10 rows)
```

Minor change based on [this](https://git.postgresql.org/gitweb/?p=postgresql.git;a=blob;f=src/test/regress/expected/window.out;h=19e2ac518afe94eed14304cb2ea42456f6288a21;hb=5c292e6b90433c760a3e15027646c7b94afd0cdd#l1483)

Since partition by four make each frame only 2 or 3 rows. and if you between 5 preceding and 6 following, then I thought in this case, rows/range frame doesn't matter. I thought range from, rows from will return the same result.  because 5 preceding 6 following covered enough 2, 3 rows per frame.

However it does matter. I guess I do understand the same query with `ROWS` instead of `RANGE`.

Quote from manual:

> In RANGE or GROUPS mode, a frame_start of CURRENT ROW means the frame
> starts with the current row's first peer row (a row that the window's
> ORDER BY clause sorts as equivalent to the current row), while a
> frame_end of CURRENT ROW means the frame ends with the current row's
> last peer row. In ROWS mode, CURRENT ROW simply means the current row.

Question: How to interpret

```
partition by four order by unique1 rows between 5::int8 preceding and 6::int2 following
```

Comment: I am curious: why the strange casts to `:int8` and `::int2`? The seem totally unnecessary.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name regress test. to test something cast.( i guess).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-WINDOW-FUNCTIONS) states:

> - In `ROWS` mode, the offset must yield a non-null, non-negative integer, and the option means that the frame starts or ends **the specified number of rows** before or after the current row.
>
> [...]
>
> - In `RANGE` mode, these options require that the `ORDER BY` clause specify exactly one column. The offset specifies **the maximum difference between the value of that column in the current row and its value in preceding or following rows** of the frame. The data type of the offset expression varies depending on the data type of the ordering column.

(The emphasis is mine.)

So with `ROWS`, you will get the 5 rows before and the 6 rows after the current row. With `RANGE`, you will get those rows where `unique1` is no more than 5 less or 6 more than the `unique1` of the current row.

In your example, if you consider the first row, `ROWS BETWEEN ... AND 6 FOLLOWING` would include the third row, but `RANGE BETWEEN ... AND 6 FOLLOWING` would not, because the difference between 8 (the value of `unique1` in the third row) and 0 is greater than 6.

Comment: allow me. Still confused. now  first sum is 4. what stop first sum become 12 (4+8) ?

Comment: For the first sum, there are no preceding rows; and the following rows are those with unique1 values <= 6(you specified) minus 0(current row)=6; only one row with this `four` value (0) satisfies this: unique1=4; the other one with unique1=8 has a difference of 8 from the current row; and exceeds what you specified (you specified 6).

Comment: OK. now I seems get it.@tinazmu. It's like for the current row compute the current row, preceding row and following row if it match the condition that x <=5 or x >=6? if so then so sum.

Comment: For RANGE, x being 'the other row's unique' - 'the current row's unique. For ROWS, x is simply the number of rows.